# copy material with python

Tags: python, rendering, color

I copy one object in Blender with python。but when I change the old object's color , the new object's color also change. I know that because the new object and the old object have the same material。my way is that：

```
obj = bpy.data.objects[old_object_name]
mesh = obj.data
new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(new_obj)
bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(object = True, obdata = True, material = True,texture = True )
```

I want to Separate the new object's material and the old object's material.when I change one object's color ,another object's color doesn't change. but my way doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

`Material.copy()` is what you want. Also you have to duplicate the object's mesh because materials link to the object's data by default.

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.context.scene
obj = bpy.context.active_object
mat = obj.active_material
mesh = obj.data

dup = bpy.data.objects.new(obj.name, mesh.copy())
dup.active_material = mat.copy()
scn.objects.link(dup)

dup.location.x += 3    # just for clarity
```

Comment: Thank you! For Blender 2.9, I changed the scn.objects line to:
```bpy.context.collection.objects.link(dup)```